# Updating to SwiftyJSON 4.0 from 3.0 causing old code to be ambiguous

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift4, swifty-json

Due to SwiftyJSON 3.0 becoming deprecated, I have updated my CocoaPods to SwiftyJSON 4.0. However I get an error from my old code.

```
 let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "jsonFile", ofType: "json") as String!      
 let readableJSON = JSON(data: jsonData! as Data, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.mutableContainers, error: nil)
```

It comes up with this error:

`Type of expression is ambiguous without more context`

I am unsure why it is now ambiguous and context it is asking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `init(data:options:` initializer in SwiftyJSON 4 `throws`

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "jsonFile", withExtension: "json")!
let jsonData = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let readableJSON = try! JSON(data: jsonData)
```

The code must not crash. If it does it reveals a design error.

The option `.mutableContainers` is pointless in Swift